# Digital clock code written in javascript displaying wrong time and offset in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time using stack flow  so please be considerate. I currently am writing a code that displays a digital clock using javascript and html. The problem I am having is the times are not accurate with the timezones offset I am trying to have them coordinate with, instead they tend to go into the negative and past 24:00:00 in military time to about 30:00:00. How would I fix this issue with my code so that it displays the right time for the time zone offsets.

Here is my code so it can be tested and compiled:

Javascript code:

```
  function startTime() {
  var d=new Date();
  var h=d.getUTCHours();
  var m=d.getUTCMinutes();
  var s=d.getUTCSeconds();
  m = checkTime(m);
  s = checkTime(s);
  document.getElementById('txt3').innerHTML = +(h-5)+":"+m+":"+s;
  document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML = +(h+11)+":"+m+":"+s;
  document.getElementById('txt2').innerHTML = +h+":"+m+":"+s;
  document.getElementById('txt4').innerHTML = +(h+8)+":"+m+":"+s;
  document.getElementById('txt5').innerHTML = +(h-10)+":"+m+":"+s;
  }
  function checkTime(i) {
  var j = i;
  if (i < 10) {
      j = "0" + i;
  }
  return j;
  }
  setInterval(function() {
  startTime();
  }, 500);

  })(jQuery);
```

HTML Code:

```
<font color="crimson" face="Montserrat">
<span style="font-size:21px; position:absolute; left:210px; top:485px;"id="txt1"></span>
</font>

 <font color="crimson" face="Montserrat">
    <span style="font-size:21px" id="txt3"></span>
      </font>

<font color="crimson" face="Montserrat">
<span style="font-size:21px; position: absolute; left:430px; top:485px;" id="txt2">.    </span>
  </font>

  <font color="crimson" face="Montserrat">
  <span style="font-size:21px; position:absolute; left:930px; top:485px;" id="txt4"></span>
    </font>

     <font color="crimson" face="Montserrat">
     <span style="font-size:21px; position:absolute; left:1150px; top:485px" id="txt5">.      </span>
     </font>
     </div>
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: When it comes to time manipulation, [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) has already all sorted out for you. You can do things like `moment().add(7, 'hours')`, job done

Comment: Did you try testing this theory? I tried testing it but it is giving me the same problem

Comment: @Johnlovescode That's not a 'theory'.  momentjs is battle-tested by thousands of programmers.  If you had the same problem there, its something you were doing.

Comment: @Johnlovescode In your code if the hour is 23 and you add 11 to it, what should the result be?  Similarly, if the hour is 4, and you subtract 8, what should the result be?

Comment: @Amy That could be possible where do you suggest I implement the momemtjs into my code? and currently the +11 is showing 28:31:20 for the time and the -4 is showing 08:31:00 but whenever the time is 1am etc it shows a negative sign

Comment: @Johnlovescode That isn't what I asked.  Answer the question I specifically asked, not the current time.  If the current hour is 23 and you add 11 hours to it, what is the expected result?  If the current hour is 4 and you subtract 8 from it, what is the expected result?  I'm trying to guide you to the answer.